# prestashop identify modified php files

Tags: prestashop

In a project already in production,

I need to recover all the prestashop files (except the modules), especially those used for order management, which no longer comply with the standards of a virgin prestashop, or rather which have already had modifications.

Do you know a way to recover all these files at once?

Answer (score 0):

Open Advanced Parameters -> Information in back office. There, you'll find a list of overrides and a list of changed files.